# Can we assign the values for PartitionKey and RowKey and timestamp in service layer. Instead of assigning in domain class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

**I am assigning the values of Partitionkey and Rowkey in domain class**

```
 private void SetRowPartitionKey()
    {
        this.PartitionKey = Constants.SecuritySchema.TABLE_NAME;
        this.RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
    }
```

**But i want to assign this in service layer. Please guide me to resolve this**

Comment: First: we don't know anything about your solution, so based on this we cannot help you. Second: `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` are 'just' properties. You can assign them anywhere.

Comment: @rickvdbosch without assigning properties in domain class we can't able to assign the values right.

Comment: Again, without us knowing anything about your solution we cannot help you. As long as the values are in the object when you persist it into storage, Azure is fine with it. Any other limitations are imposed by your implementation. Also, please refer to [ask].